# How to boot a bootable .bin file from a CD/DVD?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, dvd, bootloader, bootsector

I have written a bootable program in assembly and compiled it into a .bin file.
This is a Boot sector program which works well in Virtual box where I have to manually put the program in the offset data of the .vdi (virtual disk image) file and emulate the boot process. Till here it is working well.

But

I want to make this program bootable from a CD/DVD.

How to do that?

Comment: Use, for example, `mkisofs` tool. It has a lot of parameters, including a bootblock code source file. The ISO file created by it can be tested in virtualbox...